# How to create a custom field which queries the database?

Tags: haskell, yesod

I’m new to Yesod and would like to create a custom field in which I need to do a query.

My model is the following:

```
Article
    artname     Text
    title       Text
    body        Text
    parent      ArticleId Maybe

    UniqueArt   artname

    deriving    Typeable
```

I want to create a "parent field" in which the user enters an `artname` instead of a numerical id, but it will be the real id which will be stored in the database.

I cannot use `checkMMap` since the invert function works outside of IO.

From what I understood of the field processing, `fieldParse` takes the value entered by the user and tries to convert it to an ArticleId while `fieldView` takes an ArticleId and shows a more human version.

What I’ve come up until now is the following:

```
parentField :: Field sub ArticleId
parentField = Field
    { fieldParse = \rawVals _ -> do
            let (name:[]) = rawVals
            marticle <- runDB $ getBy (UniqueArt name)
            case marticle of
                Nothing      -> return $ (Left . SomeMessage) ("Article name invalid." :: Text)
                Just article -> return $ (Right . Just) (entityKey article)

    , fieldView = \idAttr nameAttr attrs eResult isReq ->
            case eResult of
                Right key -> do
                    marticle <- runDB $ get key
                    let name = case marticle of
                                   Just article -> Right (articleArtname article)
                                   Nothing      -> Left ("Article key invalid." :: Text)

                    (fieldView textField) idAttr nameAttr attrs name isReq

                Left _ -> (fieldView textField) idAttr nameAttr attrs eResult isReq
    }
```

GHC doesn’t like the `marticle <- runDB $ get key` line and gives me the following error:

```
Handler/Article.hs:50:21:
    Couldn't match type ‘HandlerT site1 IO’
                  with ‘WidgetT (HandlerSite sub) IO’
    Expected type: HandlerT site1 IO (Maybe Article)
                   -> (Maybe Article -> HandlerT site1 IO ())
                   -> WidgetT (HandlerSite sub) IO ()
      Actual type: HandlerT site1 IO (Maybe Article)
                   -> (Maybe Article -> HandlerT site1 IO ()) -> HandlerT site1 IO ()
    Relevant bindings include
      parentField :: Field sub ArticleId
        (bound at Handler/Article.hs:39:1)
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: marticle <- runDB $ get key
    In the expression:
      do { marticle <- runDB $ get key;
           let name = ...;
           (fieldView textField) idAttr nameAttr attrs name isReq }
    In a case alternative:
        Right key
          -> do { marticle <- runDB $ get key;
                  let name = ...;
                  (fieldView textField) idAttr nameAttr attrs name isReq }
```

Any idea ? Is it a `lift` I forgot ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to do queries inside `fieldParse` and `fieldView`, I needed some adjustments:

- the `parentField` signature must be fully specified. The `YesodPersist` and `YesodPersistBackend` constraints needs to be set because of the `runDB` calls.
- the query inside `fieldView` needs to be translated to a `Widget` because it is working inside a function that outputs a `Widget`. That’s why the `handlerToWidget` function is used.
- the original code was based on the `textField` field but this imposed other constraints. Therefore I defined my own `whamlet`.
- the `fieldEnctype` was missing.

Here is the updated source code:

```
parentField :: YesodPersist site
            => YesodPersistBackend site ~ SqlBackend
            => RenderMessage (HandlerSite (HandlerT site IO)) FormMessage
            => Field (HandlerT site IO) ArticleId
parentField = Field
    { fieldParse = \rawVals _ -> do
            let (name:[]) = rawVals
            articleM <- runDB $ getBy (UniqueArt name)
            return $ case articleM of
                Nothing      -> (Left . SomeMessage) ("Article name invalid." :: Text)
                Just article -> (Right . Just) (entityKey article)

    , fieldView = \ident name attrs resultE isReq ->
            case resultE of
                Right key -> do
                    articleM <- handlerToWidget . runDB $ get key
                    let value = case articleM of
                                   Just article -> Right (articleArtname article)
                                   Nothing      -> Left ("Article key invalid." :: Text)

                    parentHtml ident name attrs value isReq

                Left err -> parentHtml ident name attrs (Left err) isReq
    , fieldEnctype = UrlEncoded
    }
    where parentHtml ident name attrs val isReq =
            [whamlet|$newline never
                <input id="#{ident}"
                       name="#{name}"
                       *{attrs}
                       type="text"
                       :isReq:required
                       value="#{either id id val}">
            |]
```