# use runDB in a SubSite Yesod

Tags: haskell, persistence, yesod

i want create a post method in a SubSite to create a new entity, i have this AForm

```
demoForm :: RenderMessage master FormMessage => Maybe Demo -> AForm    (HandlerT master IO) Demo
demoForm   demo = Demo 
            <$> areq textField (fieldSettingsLabel ("fieldone"::T.Text))   (demoFieldOne <$> demo)
            <*> areq intField  (fieldSettingsLabel ("fieldone"::T.Text))   (demoFieldTwo <$> demo)
            <*> areq boolField (fieldSettingsLabel ("fieldThree"::T.Text)) (demoFieldThree <$> demo) 
            <*> areq dayField  (fieldSettingsLabel ("fieldFour"::T.Text))  (demoFieldFour <$> demo)
```

and the Post method:

```
   postDemoNewR :: (Yesod master,RenderMessage master FormMessage) => HandlerT DemoCrud (HandlerT master IO) Html
   postDemoNewR = do
            tp <- getRouteToParent 
            ((result,widget), encoding) <- lift $ runFormPost $ renderBootstrap3 BootstrapBasicForm $ demoForm  Nothing
            case result of
                 FormSuccess demo -> do

                             _ <- lift $  runDB $ insert demo
                             redirect DemoNewR
                 _ -> lift $ defaultLayout $ do
                 let actionR = DemoNewR                
                 [whamlet|
                    <form method=post action=@{tp DemoNewR} encType=#{encoding}>
                          ^{widget}
                    <button .btn .btn-default> default text create
               |]
```

but have the following error

```
  Could not deduce (YesodPersistBackend master
                  ~ persistent-2.1.3:Database.Persist.Sql.Types.SqlBackend)
from the context (Yesod master, RenderMessage master FormMessage)
  bound by the type signature for
             postDemoNewR :: (Yesod master, RenderMessage master FormMessage) =>
```

I thing that I need add YesodPersist but i'm not sure how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the following constraint to the `postDemoNewR` declaration:

```
YesodPersist master => YesodPersistBackend master ~ SqlBackend => …
```

The first constraint tells `master` must have persistent abilities while the second constraint tells the backend used for persistent should be an SQL backend.

[You can find something similar in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29961138/how-to-create-a-custom-field-which-queries-the-database)

Comment: Great, it works! Thanks!, i need modify the YesodDispatch, as well `instance (Yesod master,RenderMessage master FormMessage, YesodPersist master, YesodPersistBackend master ~ SqlBackend) 
      => YesodSubDispatch DemoCrud (HandlerT master IO) 
      where
     yesodSubDispatch = $(mkYesodSubDispatch resourcesDemoCrud)`